# Simple Reliable UDP C++ Libraries

Tags: c++, udp

I am in need of a reliable UDP library.  The one I wrote does not work too well and I would like to see what a 3rd party can do in the same circumstances.

Enet will not work because of some "interesting" compile issues in xcode (I have another question on stack overflow about that).

Any suggestions for a portable, reliable UDP library would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Pavel Maybe he means a *reliable library*.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky : No, "reliable UDP library" is not an oxymoron. He means a protocol built on top of UDP which guarantees delivery and order of network packets. Such a protocol still gives less latency than TCP, because TCP does bandwidth probing and buffering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). I would recommend the former over the latter.

Comment: A few years ago, whenever I'd Google "ace", the ACE library would appear on the first page of hits. It's now on page 7. It seems like it's being superseded by boost::asio.

Comment: Has anyone implemented a CORBA ORB on top of boost::asio yet?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I marked it as the answer.  But we eventually get Enet working in our xcode project.  It took all day, but we are good to go now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

UDT
udt.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I've always felt that the [Plan 9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/plan9/) networking libraries were a major upgrade over their Unix counterparts.  There is a [Unix backport](http://swtch.com/plan9port/).

Answer (score 1):

P2engine is a flexible and efficient platform for making p2p system development easier. Reliable UDP, Message Transport , Message Dispatcher, Fast and Safe Signal/Slot...

https://sourceforge.net/projects/p2engine/