# Is there Reliable UDP implementation for C++ with python asyncio bindings?

Tags: python, c++, udp, rpc, rudp

I need send and receive reliable datagrams between peers (by using RPC).
Every peer is service in service-oriented architecture.
But any peer may be written on Python or C++ (Python services with asyncio and C++ Unreal Engine 4 instances - clients and servers).

So I search for done RUDP implementations for C++ and Python both.

What are RUDP implementations best to use for this task?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think so. UDP is not reliable. TCP is, but UDP is faster. Here is a comparison between UDP and TCP on this [link](http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP), I recommend reading it.

That said, this repo claims to have TCP reliability in UDP (C++): https://github.com/dileepramesh/Reliable-UDP

Also, please take a look at this link: [Simple Reliable UDP C++ Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940106/simple-reliable-udp-c-libraries)

it recommends boost::asio and ACE.

Comment: If the answer satisfies your needs I recommend closing the question. Best of luck!